# How exactly does France's "rich tax" / "millionaire tax" of 75% above 1 million euros salary work?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, salary, france

Can someone explain how the French "rich tax" works? If I had salary of 1.000.000€ per annum, would I pay 750.000€ tax? And thus I would realize only 250.000€ net income?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A tax like this means that you pay 75% on the amount of your income over 1 million Euros. [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_France#Income_Taxes) gives the current rates. So:

Income Share    Tax Rate

Up to €6,011    0%

Between €6,012 - €11,991    5.5%

Between €11,992 - €26,631   14%

Between €26,632 - €71,397   30%

Between €71,398 - €151,200  41%

Above €151,200  45%

So if you are earning €1000001, you would pay the same tax as someone earning €1000000, plus an extra 75c.

All income taxes work this way.

Comment: When I earn 1Mio and 1€ I pay only 75Cent tax?

Comment: @DJClayworth Actually, the specific tax the OP asks about doesn't work that way. From the Wikipedia page you linked to, this: *"High earners income tax: For tax years 2013 & 2014 earnings above 1 million euros will be subject to a tax **payable by the payer/employer.** The tax introduced by Francois Hollande as the 75% tax is in fact a 50% tax which when social security charges are added reaches 75%."*  In other words, I think the employee may receive more than 25% of the amount in excess of 1,000,000, and from the employer's perspective the gross amount may exceed 1,000,000, taxes considered.

Comment: I confess I wasn't aware of the details, so I answered on the general principles of graduated taxation.

Comment: Edit. Nudge, nudge :-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to do the research to make a good answer of this. Feel free to write an answer and I will vote it up.

Comment: I edited to show full lower table prior to this change.

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean is that, for 1 000 000 € of revenue, you ll pay:

First slice (0%): 0€

Second slice (5.5%): 328.85€

Third slice (14%): 2,049.46€

Fourth slice (30%): 13,429.50€

Fifth slice (41%): 32,718.82€

Sixth slice (45%): 381,960€

Total: 430,486.63€

But at 1M€ we don t enter the last slice, 75%, let s say we get 1.5M€ instead, the first six slice doesn t change.

Last slice (75%): 375,000€

For a total of 805,486.63€, wich make ~53% of the revenue, far from 75% : )